# Justification for differentiating a Function under the integral

Tags: electromagnetism, calculus

In a physics book I'm reading the authors take this expression,
$$\phi(t)=\displaystyle\int_0^a aB(x,t)\mathrm{d}x$$

Then they differentiate with respect to time,
$$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}\phi}{\mathrm{d}t}=\displaystyle\int_0^a a\dfrac{\mathrm{d}B(x,t)}{\mathrm{d}t}\mathrm{d}x$$

I assumed that they had differentiated under the integral sign, but in that case the partial derivative of $B$ with respect to $t$ would be taken, right?
But here they use the total derivative later to state that:
$$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}B(x,t)}{\mathrm{d}t}=\dfrac{\partial B}{\partial t}+\dfrac{\partial B}{\partial x}\cdot\dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{dt}}$$

Is this correct? If so, why?

---

**EDIT:**

For reference, it is a standard physics textbook for class 12 in India.

http://www.amazon.in/Physics-Text-Book-Part-Class/dp/8174506314/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1502640532&sr=8-2&keywords=physics+ncert+class+12

The question is:

"*A square loop of side $12 \text{ cm}$ with its sides parallel to the x and y-axes is moved with a velocity of $8 \text{ cm-s}^{-1}$ in the positive x-direction in a magnetic field directed along the z-axis. This field is neither uniform in space nor constant in time. The field has a gradient of $10^{-3} \text{ T-cm}^{-1}$ and decreases with time at the rate of $10^{-3} \text{ T-s}^{-1}$. Determine the direction and magnitude of the induced current in the loop if it resistance is $4.50\text{ m}\Omega$.*"

Comment: $x$ is an integration variable. What would it mean to say that it depends on $t$? Since $x$ can't really be viewed as a function of $t$ all we can really do is treat them as independent variables and so $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} = 0$

Comment: In this case, $x$ was the the displacement along the x-axis which did vary with time because it had a velocity.

Comment: The $x$ in the expression above is can't be a function of the $t$ variable. I suggest you go back through the derivation you got this from and look very carefully at what the various quantities represent. That $t$ is not "the time at which the particle was at position $x$" (unless the writer has made a serious mistake). It may be the time at which some other even took place, or the upper limit of the integral may have a $t$ dependence (although from the expressions you have posted it doesn't seem to) the writer may also be being lazy with their variable names (this is unfortunately common)

Comment: Explicitly, **which** physics book is this based on, thanks? And could you edit it into your post please, as comments get deleted.

Comment: @BySymmetry Could you explain why $x$ can't be a function of time?

Comment: Well, because $x$ is the dummy variable, which you use for integration. If the limits of the integral depend on time, you need to use [_Leibnitz's rule_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

Comment: This appears to be Leibnitz's rule simply written with sloppy notation (using the symbol for the differentiation instead of for partial differentiation).  I think it's (another) mistake to read more into it than that.  No one said that authors didn't make mistakes.

Comment: @StephenG: That is what I assumed. But as I mentioned,  the authors proceeded to use the total derivative later and not the Leibnitz Rule.

Comment: For me, as written, the differentiation of the integral as they do it is just nonsense.  To evaluate $\frac{dB}{dt}$ requires that you know an expression for $x(t)$ (or $t(x)$ ) which makes a nonsense of the integral in the first place because it's simply reduces it to $\phi(t)=\int^a_0g(x)dx=constant$ and of course the derivative becomes zero, which all seems quite pointless.  $x$ and $t$ have to be independent to make this a non-trivial integral.

Comment: So, would you say that this is mathematically incorrect?